Flask passing kwargs to routine
I need some advice
In the  following code the WTF form gets populated with information if record_id is specified.
@app.route('/settings', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def settings(**kwargs):

 ...

    record_id_ = kwargs.pop('rec_id', 0)

    if record_id_ != 0:  # if focus record is spesified
        data = find_sql_data...
 
        # insert values into licence form
        form1.field1.data = lic_data[0][1]
        ...

    else:   # No focus record is spesified
        form1.field8.data = datetime(2000, 1, 2)
        ...

     return render_template(template_name_or_list='setup.html',
                            form1=form1, data=data, )

The problem is that when the record is NOT specified the "settings.html" renders perfectly but if a record is specified then the information is passed correctly but the Flask pathes is wrong and the CSS in not applied
The Flask path is changes from
GET /static/assets/.... to
GET /settings/static/assets/....
How do I fix the path the the CSS (and other) files
I tried to change the return redirect(url_for('settings', record_id=record_id)) to just return setting(record_id=record_id)
but that does not have the desired results either.
Also blocking the form data out does not fix the problem either

Your question is a bit unclear. What you mean by changing the source path of the server and how you use your form remains hidden. It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example. -  If you want to pass data such as an ID to another route via redirect, you can either use variable rules like you did in the first route, or use URL parameters, which can be retrieved via request.args.get(key, default=None, type=None).

It seems to me that you have specified a relative path for your CSS file within the template. This is why the path changes depending on the route. If you use url_for('static', filename=...) to include the file, the problem should be solved, as an absolute path is automatically used.
The following example shows you one possibility of what your application could look like if you were to use the URL parameters mentioned in the comment. The example uses the old legacy query interface of Flask-SQLAlchemy.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Settings</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/main.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('settings', obj_id=obj_id) }}">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        <div>
            {{ form.field1.label() }}
            {{ form.field1() }}
        </div>
        <div>
            {{ form.field2.label() }}
            {{ form.field2() }}
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

from flask import (
    Flask, 
    redirect, 
    render_template, 
    request, 
    url_for
)
from datetime import datetime
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import DateTimeField, StringField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY='your secret here', 
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///example.db'
)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Settings(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    field1 = db.Column(db.String)
    field2 = db.Column(db.DateTime)

with app.app_context():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()

class SettingsForm(FlaskForm):
    field1 = StringField()
    field2 = DateTimeField()

@app.route('/settings', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def settings():
    obj_id = request.args.get('obj_id', 0, type=int)
    obj = Settings.query.get(obj_id)
    data = { 'field2': datetime(2000, 1, 2) }
    form = SettingsForm(request.form, obj=obj, data=data)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if not obj: 
            obj = Settings()
            db.session.add(obj)
        form.populate_obj(obj)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('settings', obj_id=obj.id))
    return render_template('settings.html', **locals())

If you prefer variable rules, the following implementation is possible.
@app.route('/settings', methods=['GET', 'POST'], defaults={ 'obj_id': 0 })
@app.route('/settings/<int:obj_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def settings(obj_id=0):
    obj = Settings.query.get(obj_id)
    data = { 'field2': datetime(2000, 1, 2) }
    form = SettingsForm(request.form, obj=obj, data=data)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if not obj: 
            obj = Settings()
            db.session.add(obj)
        form.populate_obj(obj)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('settings', obj_id=obj.id))
    return render_template('settings.html', **locals())

A third possibility is to use an IntegerField with a HiddenInput as a widget to transfer the ID.
These are simplified examples.
Remember that in all variants a new database entry will be created if no existing one is found. This allows any user to expand the database without hindrance by selecting the URL. If you want to prevent this, session storage is a possible alternative.

Thank you Detlef.
Your solution works and helps a lot. I am just curios why a form without  data works and a form with data does not????
Thanks again.
